# Blender VSE (VideoSequenceEditor) Slows drastically when adding strips

Tags: video-sequence-editor

When I'm adding several strips at top of each other in VSE, it slows to one frame per second render speed, which takes even a several minutes render for, like, hours.

Is there any way to avoid this, like, changing strip overlapping settings, or is there any new updates planned for VSE?

Or, it's at the state of old Blender Render and Game Engine, left just cause it can do something?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not really a fix for something like this. You can sequence it overnight, but there is no way to speed it up unless you set the output to a lower quality